# Can't undertand this behavior of dblquad

Tags: python, integral, probability-density, quad

This is a case in which I *think* a simple integral should be 1, but dblquad stubbornly says 0.81.

The details: function createFun below returns a real function. It is piecewise linear, intended to be a density function for a random variable that takes values in [-b, 1-a]

```
def createFun(a, b):
    def fIn(x):
        if x < -a:
            return (b+x)/(b-a)
        elif x > 1-b:
            return 1 - (x-(1-b))/(b-a)
        else:
            return 1
    return fIn
```

Now for specific values a=0 and b=0.2 I build one such function.

```
a = 0.0
b = 0.2
f1 = createFun(a, b)
```

First of all, I make sure the integral in [-b, 1-a] is really 1:

```
print("Check it is a density, in [-b, 1-a]")
print(quad(f1, -b, 1-a))  # It is 1, as expected
```

Fine so far. Now, I define the function g:RxR --> R, as g(y,x) = f1(x) * f1(y).

```
def g(y, x):
    return f1(y) * f1(x)
```

I am expecting that the double integral of g in the square [-b, 1-a] x [-b, 1-a] should be the product of the integrals in each variable (g is factored as a function of x and a function of y), both are 1, so I expected 1*1=1. But the code

```
print("Now, the double integral")
print(dblquad(g, -b, 1-a, lambda _:-b, lambda _:1-a))  # Should be 1, but isn't!
```

shows 0.8161, with a very low error of order 1E-10.

Is my math wrong, and for some reason this integral is not 1? Or it is, but I am not using dblquad correctly? How should it be done, then?

Comment: Did you resolve the problem?

Comment: @Severin No, in the end I used Mathematica to obtain a formula for the integral function, in my original problem (slightly more complex than the one in this post). I still do not understand why this result is so far from 1.0

Answer (score 0):

It actually is 1:

```py
from scipy.integrate import quad, dblquad

a = 0.0
b = 0.2


def f(x):
    if x < -a:
        return (b + x) / (b - a)
    elif x > 1 - b:
        return 1 - (x - (1 - b)) / (b - a)
    else:
        return 1


print(quad(f, -b, 1 - a))


def g(y, x):
    return f(y) * f(x)


print(dblquad(g, -b, 1-a, lambda _:-b, lambda _:1-a))
```

```
(1.0, 1.1102230246251565e-15)
(1.0000000000000004, 2.55351295663786e-15)
```

Comment: With current scipy it is. But it was not back then.